# Prometheus blackbox-exporter & bearer_token renewal

Tags: authentication, prometheus, bearer-token, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Our bearer_token is valid for max. 1 h. Hence a new token has to be requested regularly.

The current implementation of blackbox-exporter does not allow to configure and use a refresh token:

```
# The bearer token for the targets.
[ bearer_token: <secret> ]

# The bearer token file for the targets.
[ bearer_token_file: <filename> ]
```

An obvious solution would be to create a cronjob requesting a new access token - using a refresh token - and writing it to `<filename>`. But wouldn't it be better to have the blackbox_exporter itself handle this?

Are there reasons to have this not implemented as part of the blackbox-exporter?